# Apache Storm 1.1.0 not running and giving Unable to read additional data from client sessionid

Tags: java, stream, real-time, apache-storm, apache-storm-topology

I am running a simple Hello World kind of application in Apache Storm 1.1.0 . Application has a random integer spout and a bolt which prints the tuple output. But somehow I am not able to get it working on my windows system.

I am new to Apache storm and following a tutorial. I have looked for the answers in stack overflow, but i was not able to find any solved question regarding the same.

Following is my run Topology code:

```
public static void runTopology() {
    //String filePath = "./src/main/resources/operations.txt";
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    builder.setSpout("randomNumberSpout", new RandomIntSpout());
    builder.setBolt("printingBolt", new PrintingBolt()).shuffleGrouping("randomNumberSpout");

    Config config = new Config();
    config.setDebug(true);
    LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
    try{
        cluster.submitTopology("Test", config, builder.createTopology());
    }finally{
        cluster.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Bolt code

```
public class PrintingBolt extends BaseBasicBolt {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector basicOutputCollector) {
        System.out.println("Printing Tupple!!!!");
        System.out.println(tuple);
        System.out.println("Tupple processed " + tuple.getInteger(1));
        basicOutputCollector.emit(new Values(tuple.getInteger(1)));
    }

    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {
        outputFieldsDeclarer.declare(new Fields("TestOutput"));

    }
}
```

Spout Code

```
public class RandomIntSpout extends BaseRichSpout {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Random random;
    private SpoutOutputCollector outputCollector;

    /*@Override
    public void open(Map<String,Object> map, TopologyContext topologyContext,
      SpoutOutputCollector spoutOutputCollector) {
        random = new Random();
        outputCollector = spoutOutputCollector;
    }*/

    public void nextTuple() {
        Utils.sleep(1000);
        outputCollector.emit(new Values(random.nextInt(), System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }

    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {
        outputFieldsDeclarer.declare(new Fields("randomInt", "timestamp"));
    }

    public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
            random = new Random();
            outputCollector = collector;
    }
}
```

I can provide the rest of the code as well, but I don't think that will be required. If required please mention in comments, I will provide that as well.

I get following error whenever I try to run the application.

10620 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2000/storm sessionTimeout=20000 > watcher=org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@31b0f02
10625 [main-SendThread(0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000)] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server > 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
10627 [main-SendThread(0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000)] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to > 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000, initiating session
10627 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory - Accepted socket connection from /> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56905
10628 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer - Client attempting to establish new session at /> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56905
10631 [main-SendThread(0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000)] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server > 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000, sessionid = 0x16a8e5abd97000d, negotiated timeout = 20000
10631 [SyncThread:0] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer - Established session 0x16a8e5abd97000d with negotiated timeout 20000 for client /> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56905

> 10632 [main-EventThread] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager - State change: CONNECTED
>   10635 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x16a8e5abd97000d type:create cxid:0x2 zxid:0x26 txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/storm/blobstoremaxkeysequencenumber > Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /storm/blobstoremaxkeysequencenumber
>   10655 [Curator-Framework-0] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl - backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
>   10657 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Processed session termination for sessionid: > 0x16a8e5abd97000d
>   10659 [main-EventThread] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
>   10659 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x16a8e5abd97000d closed
>   10661 [main] INFO  o.a.s.cluster - setup-path/blobstore/Test-1-1557166474-stormconf.ser/IBMT450PC053RLV.Corp.CVS.com:6627-1
>   10660 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - caught end of stream exception
>   org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid > 0x16a8e5abd97000d, likely client has closed socket
>   at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>   at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
>   10671 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - Closed socket connection for client /> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56905 which had sessionid 0x16a8e5abd97000d
>   10746 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl - Starting
>   10747 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2000/storm sessionTimeout=20000 > watcher=org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.curator.ConnectionState@73893ec1
>   10755 [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2000)] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2000. Will not > attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
>   10756 [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2000)] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Socket connection established to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2000, initiating > session
>   10758 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory - Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:56908
>   10759 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer - Client attempting to establish new session at > /127.0.0.1:56908
>   10766 [main-SendThread(127.0.0.1:2000)] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2000, > sessionid = 0x16a8e5abd97000e, negotiated timeout = 20000
>   10766 [SyncThread:0] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer - Established session 0x16a8e5abd97000e with negotiated timeout 20000 for client > /127.0.0.1:56908
>   10767 [main-EventThread] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager - State change: CONNECTED
>   10778 [Curator-Framework-0] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl - backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
>   10781 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Processed session termination for sessionid: > 0x16a8e5abd97000e
>   10785 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x16a8e5abd97000e closed
>   10785 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:56908 > which had sessionid 0x16a8e5abd97000e
>   10785 [main] INFO  o.a.s.cluster - setup-path/blobstore/Test-1-1557166474-stormcode.ser/IBMT450PC053RLV.Corp.CVS.com:6627-1
>   10786 [main-EventThread] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
>   10821 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.nimbus - desired replication count 1 achieved, current-replication-count for conf key = 1, current-replication-count > for code key = 1, current-replication-count for jar key = 1
>   11042 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.nimbus - Activating Test: Test-1-1557166474
>   11058 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.nimbus - Shutting down master
>   11064 [Curator-Framework-0] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl - backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
>   11066 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Processed session termination for sessionid: > 0x16a8e5abd970003
>   11068 [main-EventThread] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
>   11069 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - caught end of stream exception
>   org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid > 0x16a8e5abd970003, likely client has closed socket
>   at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>   at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
>   11068 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x16a8e5abd970003 closed
>   11069 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:56875 > which had sessionid 0x16a8e5abd970003
>   11069 [Curator-Framework-0] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl - backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
>   11072 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Processed session termination for sessionid: > 0x16a8e5abd970004
>   11074 [main-EventThread] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
>   11075 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - Closed socket connection for client /> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56878 which had sessionid 0x16a8e5abd970004
>   11074 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x16a8e5abd970004 closed
>   11077 [Curator-Framework-0] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl - backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
>   11079 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Processed session termination for sessionid: > 0x16a8e5abd970000
>   11081 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x16a8e5abd970000 closed
>   11081 [main] INFO  o.a.s.zookeeper - closing zookeeper connection of leader elector.
>   11082 [main-EventThread] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
>   11082 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:56866 > which had sessionid 0x16a8e5abd970000
>   11082 [Curator-Framework-0] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl - backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
>   11084 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Processed session termination for sessionid: > 0x16a8e5abd970001
>   11086 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x16a8e5abd970001 closed
>   11087 [main-EventThread] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
>   11087 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.nimbus - Shut down master
>   11087 [Curator-Framework-0] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl - backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
>   11089 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - caught end of stream exception
>   org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid > 0x16a8e5abd970001, likely client has closed socket
>   at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>   at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
>   11089 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:56869 > which had sessionid 0x16a8e5abd970001
>   11090 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Processed session termination for sessionid: > 0x16a8e5abd970006
>   11092 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x16a8e5abd970006 closed
>   11093 [Curator-Framework-0] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl - backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
>   11093 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - caught end of stream exception
>   org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid > 0x16a8e5abd970006, likely client has closed socket
>   at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>   at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
>   11094 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:56884 > which had sessionid 0x16a8e5abd970006
>   11095 [main-EventThread] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
>   11095 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Processed session termination for sessionid: > 0x16a8e5abd970008
>   11098 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x16a8e5abd970008 closed
>   11098 [main-EventThread] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
>   11099 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.s.ReadClusterState - Setting Thread[SLOT_1024,5,main] assignment to null
>   11099 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.s.ReadClusterState - Setting Thread[SLOT_1025,5,main] assignment to null
>   11099 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - caught end of stream exception
>   org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid > 0x16a8e5abd970008, likely client has closed socket
>   at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>   at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
>   11099 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.s.ReadClusterState - Setting Thread[SLOT_1026,5,main] assignment to null
>   11099 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.s.ReadClusterState - Waiting for Thread[SLOT_1024,5,main] to be EMPTY, currently EMPTY
>   11099 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.s.ReadClusterState - Waiting for Thread[SLOT_1025,5,main] to be EMPTY, currently EMPTY
>   11099 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - Closed socket connection for client /> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56890 which had sessionid 0x16a8e5abd970008
>   11099 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.s.ReadClusterState - Waiting for Thread[SLOT_1026,5,main] to be EMPTY, currently EMPTY
>   11099 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.s.Supervisor - Shutting down supervisor 009e412c-0d39-400c-8302-08296524c703
>   11100 [Thread-10] INFO  o.a.s.e.EventManagerImp - Event manager interrupted
>   11102 [Curator-Framework-0] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl - backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
>   11103 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Processed session termination for sessionid: > 0x16a8e5abd97000a
>   11105 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x16a8e5abd97000a closed
>   11105 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.s.ReadClusterState - Setting Thread[SLOT_1027,5,main] assignment to null
>   11105 [main-EventThread] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
>   11105 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.s.ReadClusterState - Setting Thread[SLOT_1028,5,main] assignment to null
>   11105 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.s.ReadClusterState - Setting Thread[SLOT_1029,5,main] assignment to null
>   11106 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.s.ReadClusterState - Waiting for Thread[SLOT_1027,5,main] to be EMPTY, currently EMPTY
>   11106 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.s.ReadClusterState - Waiting for Thread[SLOT_1028,5,main] to be EMPTY, currently EMPTY
>   11106 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.s.ReadClusterState - Waiting for Thread[SLOT_1029,5,main] to be EMPTY, currently EMPTY
>   11106 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.s.Supervisor - Shutting down supervisor 5daf8496-451f-43ca-b176-b16055d6183c
>   11106 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - caught end of stream exception
>   org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid > 0x16a8e5abd97000a, likely client has closed socket
>   at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>   at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
>   11106 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - Closed socket connection for client /> 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:56896 which had sessionid 0x16a8e5abd97000a
>   11106 [Thread-14] INFO  o.a.s.e.EventManagerImp - Event manager interrupted
>   11108 [Curator-Framework-0] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl - backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
>   11109 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Processed session termination for sessionid: > 0x16a8e5abd97000c
>   11112 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ZooKeeper - Session: 0x16a8e5abd97000c closed
>   11112 [main-EventThread] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.ClientCnxn - EventThread shut down
>   11112 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - caught end of stream exception
>   org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid > 0x16a8e5abd97000c, likely client has closed socket
>   at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>   at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.1.0.jar:1.1.0]
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_60]
>   11113 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:56902 > which had sessionid 0x16a8e5abd97000c
>   11114 [main] INFO  o.a.s.testing - Shutting down in process zookeeper
>   11115 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory - NIOServerCnxn factory exited run method
>   11116 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.ZooKeeperServer - shutting down
>   11116 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.SessionTrackerImpl - Shutting down
>   11116 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - Shutting down
>   11117 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.SyncRequestProcessor - Shutting down
>   11117 [SyncThread:0] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.SyncRequestProcessor - SyncRequestProcessor exited!
>   11117 [ProcessThread(sid:0 cport:-1):] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor - PrepRequestProcessor exited loop!
>   11117 [main] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.FinalRequestProcessor - shutdown of request processor complete
>   11118 [main] INFO  o.a.s.testing - Done shutting down in process zookeeper
>   11118 [main] INFO  o.a.s.testing - Deleting temporary path C:\Users\AKHAND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ae4119b4-70b3-4d04-9aee-5bfae4c4775b
>   11203 [main] INFO  o.a.s.testing - Deleting temporary path C:\Users\AKHAND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\a78b8c79-b9b3-438d-8df6-5d7bd74281fc
>   11215 [main] INFO  o.a.s.testing - Unable to delete file: > C:\Users\AKHAND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\a78b8c79-b9b3-438d-8df6-5d7bd74281fc\version-2\log.1
>   11215 [main] INFO  o.a.s.testing - Deleting temporary path C:\Users\AKHAND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\0e4fbadc-ad33-4577-9784-4cc163a778fa
>   11255 [main] INFO  o.a.s.testing - Deleting temporary path C:\Users\AKHAND~1\AppData\Local\Temp\456d6b1d-eb21-4b76-98f1-a2bb44b2aa5e
>   12197 [SessionTracker] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.SessionTrackerImpl - SessionTrackerImpl exited loop!

I am not able to understand why client socket is closed and why session is closed? I am not able to get it working. Please help.

Comment: Could you provide the full log of what is getting printed when you run the topology? The log you are posting is not an error, it's simply saying that a client disconnected from Zookeeper.

Comment: I have updated the logs, but if this is not the error, why am I not able to see the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might need to add a sleep here

```
try{
        cluster.submitTopology("Test", config, builder.createTopology());
        //Sleep here
    }finally{
        cluster.shutdown();
    }
```

Currently you are submitting the topology, and immediately shutting down. Unless you sleep a bit, your topology doesn't get a chance to run.

Comment: You are right, after applying sleep and Correct my Bolt class. It worked like a charm. I don't know how I missed this. Thanks for your help.